# Ubuntu 20.04 freezing on Dell Latitude 3410

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, dell

I have a Dell Latitude 3410 that contains 4-core Intel i7 processors, 16 GB RAM and integrated Intel graphics drivers. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (with 5.4.0-84-generic kernel) on this machine. One thing I have noticed is that laptop is unable to wake up when it goes to sleep or suspend states. I have to reboot the machine to get it to work. Sometimes it hangs like with a black screen after 2 or 3 hours; on some other occasions, it freezes after more than 20 hours.

As per Dell's advice, I ran various hardware tests to ensure hardware is fine. Software seems to be the issue. I have tried various solutions such as upgrading BIOS to the latest version, adding a line (GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1") to /etc/default/grub. Nothing seems to fix the problem. How to resolve this? Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: BTW, I have disabled secure boot and the fingerprint sensor as well.

Comment: I have freeze issue at the login but would be able to boot in by going to the recovery mode and then resume (via grub menu, advance options for ubuntu <kernel version>). 
For me it seems like some conflict while loading the network drivers as when I boot via the recovery mode route, I don't have control for brightness.

Is it the same issue you are facing?